# Función que coloree las celdas de una tabla cuando pasa el mouse por encima, el usuario determinar los colores con tres botones

Tags: javascript

mi consulta de hoy seria como puedo hacer la función para que una celda cambie de color cada vez que pasa por encima

```js
function cambiacolor(v) {
  document.getElementById(v).style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

```css
td{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td id="cel1"onmouseover="cambiacolor('cel1');"></td>
      <td id="cel2"onmouseover="document.getElementById('cel2').style.backgroundColor='red';"></td>
      <td id="cel3"onmouseover="document.getElementById('cel3').style.backgroundColor='red';"></td>
      <td id="cel" onmouseover="document.getElementById('cel').style.backgroundColor=document.getElementById('eo').value;
         "></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <input type="text" id="eo" />
   </tr>
</table>
```

la idea principal es hacer una imitación de Paint, se selecciona un color y se pinta con ese color la 'tabla'

este es un simple código que cree yo, la idea es hacerlo como mínimo con una estructura de 50x50 celdas

Pd: hay alguna forma de hacer una estructura repetido con el uso de div y un" for"?

tengo que agregar que estoy muy agradecido con la ultima pregunta que se resolvió

Comment: la pregunta es la de la posdata, o cual?

Comment: todo en si es la pregunta, lo principal es hacer una funcion que me permita dar  un fondo a la celda cuando pase el mouse por encima

Answer (score 3):

¡Que interesante aplicación!

Vas por muy buen camino y tienes razón con lo que supones, con un par de `for`s se pueden crear elementos de manera dinámica. Yo no crearía `<div>`s porque si vas a seguir este método de usar una tabla podrías usar los elementos de las tablas `<tr>` y `<td>`.

Te doy estos tips:

- Utiliza dos `for`: uno para recorrer las columnas y  otro para las filas.
- Genera los elementos de manera dinámica por medio de `createElement`.
- Una vez generados tus elementos puedes agregarlos como hijos con `appendChild` y haciendo referencia otro elemento que sería el "padre".
- Deja tu tabla vacía, obtén la referencia de ella utilizando `getElementById` y luego le adjuntas las filas (que a su vez ya tienen las columnas si hicistes tus iteraciones bien). En otras palabras... Construye la tabla por medio de JS.
- Cuando utilizas un evento puedes usar la propiedad `currentTarget` para hacer referencia al elemento que activó el evento, de esta manera puedes cambiar su estilo de manera dinámica y no repetir código.

Te invito también que le eches un ojo a [la solución](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqb30s4c/) de [VRoxa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/131018/vroxa), que usa no utiliza bucles `for`.

```js
function crearMatriz(filas, columnas) {
  //Obtenemos la referencia de la tabla principal por su ID (que está vacia)
  const tabla = document.getElementById("tablaPrincipal");

  //Utilizamos un for para recorrer las filas
  for (let i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
    //Creamos la fila que es un elemento html de tipo <tr>
    let fila = document.createElement("tr");

    //Utilizamos otro for para recorrer las columnas
    for (let j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {

      //Creamos la columna que es un elemento html de tipo <td>
      let columna = document.createElement("td");

      //Les damos un ID unico descriptivo
      columna.id = `celx${i}y${j}`;

      //Le ponemos el eventListener para saber cuando el mouse pasa sobre los elementos
      columna.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        //Utilizando el evento ( 'e' ) y la propiedad currentTarget podemos cambiar el estilo del cuadro que activó nuestro evento
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      });

      //Agregamos cada columna a la fila
      fila.appendChild(columna);
    }

    //Agregamos cada fila (que incluye cada columna) a la tabla
    tabla.appendChild(fila);
  }
}

//Invocamos nuestra función con la cantidad de filas y columnas que queremos
crearMatriz(50, 50);
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaPrincipal" border="1">

</table>
```

Si tienes más preguntas sobre esta aplicación voy a estar atento, me gustan este tipo de aplicaciones visuales interactivas. Suerte programando.

### UPDATE: Tip extra ¡Utiliza el click!

```js
function crearMatriz(filas, columnas) {
  //Obtenemos la referencia de la tabla principal por su ID (que está vacia)
  const tabla = document.getElementById("tablaPrincipal");

  //Utilizamos un for para recorrer las filas
  for (let i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
    //Creamos la fila que es un elemento html de tipo <tr>
    let fila = document.createElement("tr");

    //Utilizamos otro for para recorrer las columnas
    for (let j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {

      //Creamos la columna que es un elemento html de tipo <td>
      let columna = document.createElement("td");

      //Les damos un ID unico descriptivo
      columna.id = `celx${i}y${j}`;

      //Le ponemos el eventListener para saber cuando el mouse pasa sobre los elementos
      columna.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {

        //Chequeamos si el mouse tiene el botón presionado 
        if (e.buttons == 1) {
          //Utilizando el evento ( 'e' ) y la propiedad currentTarget podemos cambiar el estilo del cuadro que activó nuestro evento
          e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

        }

      });

      //Agregamos cada columna a la fila
      fila.appendChild(columna);
    }

    //Agregamos cada fila (que incluye cada columna) a la tabla
    tabla.appendChild(fila);
  }
}

//Invocamos nuestra función con la cantidad de filas y columnas que queremos
crearMatriz(50, 50);
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaPrincipal" border="1">

</table>
```

Comment: +1. Precisamente estaba escribiendo la solución y también pensé el tema de presionar el botón, porque se hace molesto que se pinten "sin querer", jaja. Por la gracia, [lo que estaba desarrollando](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqb30s4c/) so far. PS: no soporto los `for` c:

Comment: Btw, @yehoshuazuñiga. Lo suyo sería poner un *color picker*, no un `input` de `text`

Comment: @VRoxa De hecho cuando lo estaba haciendo pensé en hacer una implementación igual que la tuya, hacer el array y luego utilizar `forEach`, sin embargo, cuando es alguien que pareciera ser principiante siempre prefiero usar `for` por fines didácticos. ¿Puedo agregar tu fiddle a la respuesta, acreditandote por su puesto?

Comment: Por supuesto, todo tuyo.

Comment: hola, muhcas gracias por las prontas repuestas y perdon por responder tan tarde, estoy en proceso de aprendizaje aun, por eso  aun es limitado mi conocimiento de las estructuras de codigo,

Comment: hola,@VRoxa y **FranAcuna** muchas gracias por las prontas respuestas, y perdon por contestar  tan tarde, hace unos meses empece a estudiar programacion por eso es aun limitado mi conocimiento, ruego que me disculpen , y **FranAcuna** en cuanto tenga nuevas ideas sobre esto de los primeros en enterarte